# Как получить сегодняшний день не по дате телефона, а по глобальной дате?

Tags: android

Я хочу ввести в своё приложение монеты, которые пользователи получают при входе в приложение 1 раз в день. Но проблема в том, что пользователь может просто изменить дату в телефоне и получать таким образом монетки (с обходом системы). Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог так делать. И как вариант мне приглянулась идея взять дату не с телефона, а вот глобальную (или как она там называется) дату, потому что он не может её изменять. Скажите пожалуйста как взять текущий день не с телефона, а вот глобальную
Это в MainActivity

```
TimeLookup timeLookup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        long returnTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
        Date time = new Date(returnTime);
        Log.d("mylog","Time from " + TIME_SERVER + ": " + time);
    }
```

они подсвечиваются красными и им нужен Exception
**getByName**
**getTime**

Comment: Вам нужна какая-то внешняя система времени. К примеру вы можете синхронизировать время с сервером или каким-то удаленным сервисом.

Comment: используйте FireBase где при входе вы анализируете текущую дату и факт получения монет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот например есть [способ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818086/android-get-current-utc-time):

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
String gmtTime = df.format(new Date());
```

так же есть и второй вариант, о котором вам сказали в комментарии - брать время извне из какого-то сервиса. Можно использовать NTP (Network Time Protocol). Например, добавляем зависимость:

```
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'
```

дальше получаем время:

```
public class TimeLookup {
    public static final String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
        long returnTime = timeInfo.getReturnTime();
        Date time = new Date(returnTime);
        System.out.println("Time from " + TIME_SERVER + ": " + time);
    }

}
```

вот есть [список серверов](https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi#) с которых можно взять время. Но вам стоит учитывать что для этого нужно будет включить интернет.

Comment: Я использовал ваш первый пример где DateFormat  и она возвращает время из телефона. т.е когда я меняю время на телефоне, она тоже меняется, а эьто не совсем то что мне нужно. Попробую 2й метод...

Comment: А во втором способе в main(Массив) какой массив нужно передать?

Comment: это джава код если что) обычный класс, и главный метод, используйте то что в методе и не смотрите на аргументы метода

Comment: Понял) А почему первый пример берет локальные данные с телефона?)

Comment: что значит почему?

Comment: Ну у меня же вопрос заключается в том, чтобы получить дату из внешнего какого-то источника. А она с телефона берет. Я думал вы указали ее как способ взять из внешнего источника...

Comment: этим способом можно взять дату с 1970 года без привязки к вашему поясу

Comment: Но она всё равно меняется в зависимости от времени установленной в телефоне. Она не подходит, так как пользователи смогу поменяв дату получать монетки. В любом случае спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав галочку слева от него

Comment: Я добавил код в вопрос, посмотри пж что я делаю не так? почему в Lod Кате не появляется ничего? Библеотеку я тоже добавил

Comment: вам в oncreate нужно поместить то что внутри main функции и не нужно классы лепить для этого, в логах может быть не видно потому что вы не настроили их на нужные вам логи

Comment: Ты очередной раз помог мне. Спасибо тебе за всё (черное братское сердечко) - смайлик